# Flutter - Listview.builder inside another Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, flutter

I want my screen to be scrollable so I put everything in a Listview.

Now I want to show another Listview inside to show details of a List. When I try this an error is thrown - " Expanded widgets must be placed inside Flex widgets."

[image]

Comment: Add shrinkwrap: true in listview.builder

Comment: Remove the top most container or replace it with column

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Add `shrinkWrap: true` in `listView.builder` & Remove the top most `Container` or replace it with `Column`.

Comment: thank you, this was particularly helpful for placing a listview.builder inside a listView but without the usage of Expanded...

Comment: note that this will render all of the widgets that inner list contains, meaning it will cause problems with infinite lists or very big ones

Answer (score 57):

Adding `shrinkWrap: true, physics: ScrollPhysics(),` inside the listview.builder, in this case the listview.builder need an expanded parent. The `physics: ScrollPhysics()` will allow it to maintain its state without scrolling back to the first items. Also, you can use `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`, if you don't want the listview.builder to be scrolled by the user.

Comment: Great! Thanks @CodeMemory, it works perfectly for ListView.builder with dynamics data.

Answer (score 15):

> I want my screen to be scrollable so I put everything in a Listview.

I think you should use a [CustomScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) with slivers instead.

If it's the first time your hear about slivers, or if they seem a little bit scary, I suggest you to read this excellent [article](https://medium.com/flutter-io/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f) written by Emily Fortuna.

In your case, I would do something like this:

```
return CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      // Put here all widgets that are not slivers.
      child: Container(),
    ),
    // Replace your ListView.builder with this:
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile();
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue when I used **two** ListViews, one inside another. Nothing has worked for me except this workaround.

In the nested Listview, cover it with a ConstrainedBox and give it some large height. and use 'shrinkWrap: true' both ListViews. Since the shrinkwrap will trim the extra space, that extra height won't be an issue.

```
Flexible(
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      //other Widgets here ...
      ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 1000), // **THIS is the important part**
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => _buildRow(index),
          itemCount: _elements.length,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, adding `physics: ScrollPhysics(),` in the `ListView.builder` made the ListView.builder scrollable.

The hierarchy was  **ListView** > **StreamBuilder** > **RefreshIndicator** > **ListView.builder** .

Answer (score 7):

*It actually depends on your layout. Possible cases could be:*

- **Using `ListView` + `ListView`:**

  If you want to give your second `ListView` full height.

  ```dart
  ListView(
    children: [
      // Your other widgets ...
      ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true, //    <-- Set this to true
        physics: ScrollPhysics(), // <-- Also change physics
        itemBuilder: ...,
      ),
    ],
  )
  ```
- **Using `ListView` + `ListView`:**

  If you want to limit the height of your second `ListView`.

  ```dart
  ListView(
    children: [
      // Your other widgets ...
      SizedBox( //             <-- Use SizedBox
        height: 160, 
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: ...,
        ),
      ),
      // Your other widgets ...
    ],
  )
  ```
- **Using `Column` + `ListView`:**

  If you don't have too many (or too big) children in your first `ListView`, replace it with a `Column`.

  ```dart
  Column(
    children: [
      // Your other widgets ...
      Expanded( //              <-- Use Expanded
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: ...,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
  ```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve the problem by wrapping main column inside a SingleChildScrollView, then wrapping the ListView.builder inside a Container giving container a specified height, and then wrapping that container inside a SingleChildScrollView again.
I know it's a but complex, but it worked for me!
you can have a clear picture by the code.

```
 Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      title: Text("Welcome, ${widget.myUser.name}"),
      actions: [
        InkWell(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
            child: Icon(Icons.settings),
          ),
          onTap: () {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
    body: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            _customerDetailsWidget(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Container(
              child: Divider(
                color: Colors.grey[500],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            _addProductText(),
            SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  height: 500,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount:1,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(child: Text("HELLO WORLD"));
                    },
                  ),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you. I additional add SingleChildScrollView in ListView.build set shrinkWrap value to true.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.builder(
  physics: ScrollPhysics(),

  itemCount: question.questionByPage.value.data.length,

  shrinkWrap: true,

  primary: false,

  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListView.builder(

    physics: ScrollPhysics(),

    shrinkWrap: true,

    itemCount: question.questionByPage.value

        .data[index].questions.length,

    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int qIndex) {

      var mydata = question.questionByPage.value

          .data[index].questions[qIndex];

      return ListView.builder(

        physics: ScrollPhysics(),

        shrinkWrap: true,

        itemCount: mydata.options.length,

        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int oIndex) {

          var option = mydata.options[oIndex];

          return Column(
       
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

            children: [
           

              Text(
                mydata.description.toString(),

                textAlign: TextAlign.left,

              ),
              Text(

                option.optionText.toString(),

                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),

            ],
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
),
```