# ListView.builder disappears inside ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

`Listiew( children: [ ....., ListView.builder() ])`
My widget structure  is something like this..

but my ListView builder items disappears

Comment: use [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) with multiple slivers, for example `SliverList`s

Comment: why you need to two listView, any way you will "shrinkWrap: true" in second "ListView.builder"

Comment: My screen has multiple widgets in vertical list that's why I needed it

Comment: you can take a reference through this document, Thanks [ListView StackOverFlow Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465394/flutter-listview-builder-inside-another-listview)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the parent ListView doesn't know how many items child ListView has which causes unbounded height error.

Setting `shrinkWrap` to `true` in child ListView will fix your problem. This way the child ListView will be shrinked by evaluating all of its children upfront and treated as a single widget. Although its very costly operation.

**Costly solution:**

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text("Listview inside a Listview"),
    ),
    body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          Color randomColorforInnerlist = randomColor();
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 5,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 25,
                  color: randomColorforInnerlist,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Center(child: Text((index + 1).toString())),
                );
              });
        }));
```

Cost effective solution would be build SliverList and render that inside CustomScrollView, like this:

**Optimized Solution:**

```
List<SliverList> outerLists = [];

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      final _innerList = [];
      Color colorForInnerList = randomColor();
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        _innerList.add(Container(
          height: 25,
          color: colorForInnerList,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Center(child: Text((j + 1).toString())),
        ));
      }
      outerLists.add(
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) => _innerList[index],
            childCount: _innerList.length,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Listview inside a Listview"),
        ),
        body: CustomScrollView(slivers: outerLists),
        );
  }

  Color randomColor() =>
      Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);
```

Comment: Learn more about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUqDNnv_dh0

Answer (score 0):

Didnot quite got what you want. This is what I suggest according my understanding.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  var list1 = [
    "JhI2",
    "ddfs",
    "asdf",
    "asdfsghf",
    "sdafg",
    "asdf",
    "asdfsd",
    "dsfbg",
    "sdafsgb",
    "Asder3e",
    "asdfewgrbdvc",
    "afdscvx"
  ];
  var list2 = [3454, 3545, 35, 123, 1234, 124334, 213423, 2454, 3565];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Check")),
        body: ListView(children: [
          Text("zcvbn".toString()),
          TextField(),
          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list2.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                return Text(list2[i].toString());
              }),
          TextField(),
          Text("zcvbn".toString()),
          TextField(),
          Text("zcvbn".toString()),
        ]));
  

}
}
```